# Migrating to Heroku from Parse, but Parse.Configuration.Builder won't resolve

Tags: android, heroku, parse-platform

I am stuck on the last step trying to migrate my android app to heroku. In my android app I need to initialize my parse server by using a Parse.Configuration.Builder, but 'Configuration' is in red and I cannot figure out how to resolve the issue.

I have been referencing the parse server on github here:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example

it gives this boilerplate code for initializing your android app to use heroku:

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).applicationId("myAppId").clientKey("myClientKey").server("http://myServerUrl/parse/").build());
```

When I create a new project I do not get the error, but I have checked the build files and manifest against the old project and cannot figure out what the hold up could be.

Here is my application class:

```
package oneonanyone.com.fantasybasketball_1onany1;

import com.parse.Parse;

public class StatSelectApplication extends android.app.Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    //Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxx", "xxxxx");

    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId("xxxxx")
            .clientKey("xxxxx")
            .server("http://xxxxx.herokuapp.com/parse/")
            .build());
    }
}
```

build.grade

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "oneonanyone.com.fantasybasketball_1onany1"
    minSdkVersion 15

    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable true

    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
        }
    }
}
}

dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'


compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
compile fileTree('libs')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:wakeful:1.0.+'
```

}

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      package="oneonanyone.com.fantasybasketball_1onany1">

<uses-sdk/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<!--
 To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect
 option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>

<!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

<application
    android:name=".StatSelectApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launch"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".DraftListActivity"
        android:label="PlayerListActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="Darkhorse"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MatchUpActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_matchup"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MatchUpResultsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game_results"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login.SignUpAtivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up_ativity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ResultsActivityNew"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_results"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".LeaderBoardActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_leader_board"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".AlternateDraftActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alternate_draft"/>

    <receiver android:name=".UpdateBackend">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>
```

And my project gradle just in case:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta5'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
}
```

I could not find anyone else having this error. Any solution would be most appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Clean and Rebuild the project?

Comment: yes, clean rebuild didn't do it for me, but I may have gotten the problem solved.

Comment: @ithinkthereforeIprogr'am' how did you solve the problem?

Comment: I have since started remaking my app using a different backend. I am not an experienced developer but what I remember is that I was not able to resolve this issue without creating a new android studio project. I don't think I ever figured out the conflict. I think when I said I had gotten the problem solved I was mistaken.

Comment: This is happening for me as well. Would appreciate any input if someone has managed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check answer here: [connecting android to local parse server cannot resolve symbol Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972962/connecting-android-to-local-parse-server-cannot-resolve-symbol-configuration)

I had the Parse library as a jar in the libs folder. Solved the issue by deleting it and compiling from Gradle instead.