# connecting android to local parse server cannot resolve symbol Configuration

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have created a chat app for android, and I just installed Parse Server on my local machine. I am trying to connect the app to my parse server but...

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId("@string/parse_app_id")
            .clientKey("@string/parse_client_key")
            .server("xxxxxxxx")
            .build());
```

At Parse.**Configuration**.Builder... I am getting the unresolved symbol error.
Using Parse 1.4

```
compile files('libs/Parse-1.4.0.jar')
```

Is there anything I'm missing? Any dependencies I should add?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I just fixed that by removing the Parse 1.4.0 jar, and instead, compiling

```
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1'
```

Hope this helps someone :)

Also if Parse 1.4.0 is present when you compile, it won't work. I had to delete that completely.